# How to convert a random string to integer to derive another integer and then convert these to String to be sent to the JSON Payload

Tags: java, json, cucumber, httpclient

I have a JSON request payload where i need to pass 2 values:
value-1- This is a random number of 10 digitis example: 8000000000
value-2- this is an incremented number but only has substring which include only the last 4 digits of an incremented number of value-1- i.e. if i increase 80000000000 (which is my value-1) by 1000 i will get 8000001000, so in value 2 i only want to display the last 4 digits which is 1000

I generated the random string for value-1 by using the below code-

```
Generex generex = new Generex(regex); //where regex is 8605005[0-9]{3}
String randomString = generex.random();
System.out.println("This is the Random number->" + randomString);
```

Now I am parsing the String to an Integer by using the below code:

```
int startnumbervalue; 
    try {
        startnumbervalue = Integer.parseInt(randomString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("This is the start number->"+startnumbervalue);
}
```

Its giving an error on initialize variable, for startnumbervalue, however when I assign `int startnumbervalue = randomstring` - it gives an error saying Change type of `startnumbervalue` to `String`.

> Also, in my method i have 4 arguments:
>
> ```
> `String regex` // to pass the value to get the random number- here i am passing- 8605005[0-9]{3}
>
> `String key`  // to store the random value generated - this is my value-1
>
> `String counter` // to get the stop range
>
> `String endrange` // the counter and the value 1 needs to be added to get the end range and subsequently i need to substring this to get only the last 4 digits.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First issue)

You have to initallize your `startnumbervalue` variable with some default number, use 0 or -1 or whatever, because you are assigning a value to it in a try-catch block but your print statement is not inside that block. If you don't want to assign a default value you've to put your print statement inside the try block.

Second issue)

The maximum value that an int variable can store is 2,147,483,647 but the number your are trying to parse is larger, so it doesn't fit in an int type. Change the type to long. a long type variable can store values up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

```
    Generex generex = new Generex("8605005[0-9]{3}"); 
    String randomString = generex.random();
    System.out.println("This is the Random number->" + randomString);
    long startnumbervalue = 0; // changed to long 
    try {
        startnumbervalue = Long.parseLong(randomString);   // changed to Long.parseLong
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
        System.out.println("This is the start number->"+startnumbervalue);
    }
```

In my opinion you don't need the try-catch block at all because your regex always returns a string with ten digits. You can remove it completely:

```
    Generex generex = new Generex("8605005[0-9]{3}"); 
    String randomString = generex.random();
    System.out.println("This is the Random number->" + randomString);

    long startnumbervalue = Long.parseLong(randomString);        
    System.out.println("This is the start number->"+startnumbervalue); 

    long lastFourDigits = startnumbervalue % 10000;
    System.out.println("last four digits: "+lastFourDigits);
```